# Accessing non-static variables from another class?

Tags: android, facial-identification

I'm developing an Android app for gender recognition.

Now I want to access the classification result saved as a non-static String, `public String GENDER`, in `public class Camera2BasicFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`. I want to access it from `MainActivity` class.

I have a classification method in my `Camera2BasicFragment` class.

```
private void classifyFrame() {
    if (gclassifier == null || eclassifier == null || getActivity() == null || cameraDevice == null) {
      showToast("Uninitialized Classifier or invalid context.");
      return;
    }
    Bitmap bitmap_g =
        textureView.getBitmap(GenderClassifier.DIM_IMG_SIZE_X, GenderClassifier.DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y);
    Bitmap bitmap_e =
            textureView.getBitmap(EmotionClassifier.DIM_IMG_SIZE_X, EmotionClassifier.DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y);
    GENDER = gclassifier.classifyFrame(bitmap_g);
    EMOTION = eclassifier.classifyFrame(bitmap_e);
    String textToShow =  GENDER + EMOTION;
    bitmap_g.recycle();
    bitmap_e.recycle();
    showToast(textToShow);
  }
```

When I access the variable from `MainActivity` as follows, it gives me a NullPointerException.

```
if (Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance().GENDER.equals("female")) {
      speech = dialogs.greetings.get("female_senior_happiness");
    }
```

I tried to use a getter method in `Camera2BasicFragment` class as follows.

```
public Bitmap bitmap_g; // Passes the bitmap for gender classification. 
public String classifyGender(Bitmap bitmap) {
    return gclassifier.classifyFrame(bitmap);
  }
```

However, the passed-in bitmap variable is also null.

I know this sounds like a common problem, but I'm a little bit clueless. Really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Update codes in `MainActiivty`.

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    if (null == savedInstanceState) {
      getFragmentManager()
              .beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.container, Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance())
              .commit();
    }
    mRobotAPI = new RobotAPI(this, robotCallback);
    dialogs = new Dialogs();

    //Initial speech config
    speakConfig.timeout(30);
    speakConfig.volume(60);
    speakConfig.languageId(DialogSystem.LANGUAGE_ID_ZH_TW);
    speakConfig.alwaysListenState(SpeakConfig.MODE_FOREVER);
  }

  //public String gender = Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance().classifyGender(Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance().bitmap_g);
  //public String emotion = Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance().EMOTION;

  public void sayWithExpression(){
    String speech = "Hello World";
    if (Camera2BasicFragment.GENDER.equals("female")) {
      speech = dialogs.greetings.get("female_senior_happiness");
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "say /w ex " + speech);

    //In debugging mode we ignore this for efficiency
    //mRobotAPI.robot.setExpression(generate_expression(speech));
    mRobotAPI.robot.setExpression(RobotFace.HAPPY);
    mRobotAPI.robot.speak(speech, speakConfig);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mRobotAPI.robot.registerListenCallback(robotListenCallback);
    sayWithExpression();
  }

...
```

Comment: Camera2BasicFragment is implemented by you?

Comment: @mangusta Yeah, it is just a normal class.

Comment: so when is "classifyFrame" method invoked? if it's not invoked inside "newInstance( )", not suprising that GENDER is null

Comment: @mangusta Yes sir, that's the problem. I understand why it is null. I have no clue how to access the variable from MainActivity correctly.

Comment: is your `classifyFrame()` method called before you call `if (Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance().GENDER.equals("female")){...}`?

Comment: can you make private void classifyFrame() this method public then access by creating class instance like Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance().classifyFrame() to access classifyFrame() method.

Comment: @ShreyGarg I think so. I uploaded codes from MainActivity above.

Comment: `Camera2BasicFragment.GENDER` -> looks like you have made GENDER variable as static. You can make it non-static and should have a member variable in your `MainActivity`, i.e, `Camera2BasicFragment fragment = Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance();` then use this `fragment` in your MainActivity's `onCreate` and `onResume` (i.e, in `sayWithExpression` method)

Comment: Great, did it work?

Comment: @ShreyGarg Wait a sec. I'm trying to start a new followup to paste my code.

Comment: @ShreyGarg It seems I don't have enough reputations, so I'll just comment here. I tried to declare ```public String GENDER``` in ```Camera2BasicFragment``` class and access it with ```fragment.GENDER.equals("female")```, it is still null. I guess the ```GENDER``` variable is only a pass-by value in the method and it is not modified after its initialization.

Comment: @ShreyGarg I also tried to make ```classifyFrame()``` return ```GENDER```  and access by ```fragment.classifyFrame()```,but it always enters the first if statement in the classifyFrame() method. Thank for your timely reply, you may start a new answer below so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: @ChrisSun, I have added an answer with the same, please upvote/accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Camera2BasicFragment.GENDER` -> looks like you have made GENDER variable as static, you can make it non-static and should have a member variable in your MainActivity, i.e,

`Camera2BasicFragment fragment = Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance();`

then use this `fragment` in your MainActivity's `onCreate` and `onResume` (i.e, in `sayWithExpression` method)

Comment: he did not make it static, his words: "I want to access the classification result saved as a non-static String". and what's the difference of making it static or non-static? as long as it is public, and as long as newInstance returns an object of his class, he's going to get that gender string. The issue is when the classification is done - BEFORE he accesses that string or AFTER

Comment: @mangusta, making it static or non-static will only make a difference if he is creating multiple instances of his class and using them together. I agree with your point though.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually I noticed I phrased a wrong way. It is actually a problem with accessing the Fragment variables from the MainActivity. For those of you who have the same problem as me, I solved it by following this turotial (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface)